# Page load animation is flickering (zoom changing) while loading

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome

Our Angular (v7) app has a splash animation that basically shows a rotating wheel (CSS animation) embedded into the index.html, so it shows instantly on page load.

This works fine, however every ~4 page loads there is a slight flicker of the zoom level (I am using the latest Chrome on Windows 10), meaning the square div which holds the "splash message" starts at one size, and then drops in about 5% of it's size. It happens very fast and about a second from the moment the static HTML contents are rendered to view, and before the Angular view is rendered. And it looks like some of the rendering engine is getting loaded lazily and something goes wrong (?)

Could it be that Angular is changing zoom/translation factor on page load?

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="mitzi-page-root">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      .mitzi-splash-view-indicator {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
        animation: fadein 2s;
      }

      @keyframes fadein {
        from { opacity: 0; }
        to   { opacity: 1; }
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
        from { opacity: 0; }
        to   { opacity: 1; }
      }

      .mitzi-splash-indicator-dialog-bg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 15rem;
        height: 12rem;
        align-self: center;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: .1rem;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border-color: #378b68;
        -webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
        animation: fadein 5s;
      }

      .mitzi-splash-indicator-loader-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        left: 4.6875rem;
        top: 2.2495rem;
        width: 5.625rem;
        height: 5.625rem;
        padding-bottom: 3rem;
      }

      .mitzi-splash-indicator-loader {
        width: 5.625rem;
        height: 5.625rem;
        align-self: center;
        animation: mitzi-splash-indicator-spin 1s steps(8) infinite;
      }

      .mitzi-splash-indicator-message {
        position: absolute;
        top: 9.125rem;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        height: 1rem;
        line-height: 1rem;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #2A6E52;
      }

      @keyframes mitzi-splash-indicator-spin {
        0% {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }

      .mitzi-splash-indicator-spinner {
        fill: #0c573c;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="32x32" href="assets/img/favicon-mitzi.png" type="image/png" />
  </head>
  <body class="mitzi-body">
    <mitzi-root>
    </mitzi-root>
    <div id="mitzi_app_preloader" class="mitzi-splash-view-indicator">
      <div class="mitzi-splash-indicator-dialog-bg">
        <div class="mitzi-splash-indicator-loader-wrapper">
          <div class="mitzi-splash-indicator-loader">
            <svg class="mitzi-splash-indicator-spinner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" style="background: none;">
              <!-- HERE COMES SOME **STATIC** SVG GRAPHICS THAT IS BEING ROTATED BY **CSS** (AND NOT BY SVG ANIMATIONS - WHICH *WOULD* MESS THINGS UP)... -->
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="mitzi-splash-indicator-message">Loading ...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none !important" id="hidden-div-for-assets-load-on-startup">
      <img src="assets/img/common/error.svg">
      <img src="assets/img/status_icons/form_error.png">
      <span class="pi pi-times"></span>
    </div>
    <title>mitzi</title>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us some code although I am sure it is nothing related to it

Comment: added my index.html

Answer (score 0):

box-sizing was set by our own code .... which triggered a minor change in the size of the div